# MySql - Where are the pending processes?

Tags: mysql

I am launching hundreds of php scripts simultaneously. To have an overview of the 'activty', I am doing a SHOW PROCESSLIST in mySql. This returns 5 processes including the SHOW PROCESSLIST one. So I am wondering where all the other pending processes are before being processed. Is there a command to see those? Thank you for your replies. Cheers. Marc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
```

If you not see what you are expecting, then PHP script is not making query in the time this select runs.

More info about server threads you can find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/thread-information.html)

You can also use [mysqlproxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy) to see everything.

Comment: Hello rkosegi. The query your suggested is also only returning 5 rows (including your query). I don't get it as when I check snapshots of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST on the internet, there a lot of rows, and not only 5. Do you know what can explain this behavior?

Comment: How much time takes your queries? in case of simple selects, you will not see them, please check mysqlproxy, it can be helpfull, you can see queries online how they comes to server

Comment: My queries are long queries that collect data and then insert those data into my db. Approximately 400 row inserted per file. And I have a little more than hundred files triggered simultaneously. Each php file runs approx 10 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

See the manual, and in particular:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html

> If you have the PROCESS privilege, you can see all threads. Otherwise,
>   you can see only your own threads (that is, threads associated with
>   the MySQL account that you are using)

Maybe the php script and the client doing SHOW PROCESSLIST are using a different account ...

Comment: Hello Marc. Thanks for trying to help. The thing is that I am the only user. So everything is triggered with the same account. The processlist only has at any time 5 processes eventhough I launched 100 queries. When a process from the processlist is finished, it disappears from the list and is replaced by one process that was on 'queue'. I am investigating if it might be related to the fact that I am trigeering the hundred queries at the exact same time...